# HTML rendering of Bluemix Conversation response

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I defined the response of the Conversation service as described her: http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/dialog_ovw.shtml#dialog_create in the big advanced editor window.

```
"output": {
    "text": "Visit IBM Support <a href=\"http://www.ibm.com/support\">here</a>."
}
```

However, the editor is in a red-colored frame and when I click on the twistie twice the original text appears and the HTML text is gone.

[image: Adding Hyperlink to response]

Comment: Do you have screenshots of what you are seeing?

Comment: Sure, I added screenshots.

Comment: Reproduced. Looks like a bug. No answer I can give you. :(  Can you log a bug with Bluemix Support.

Comment: done, feedback from developer: The input should have at least an outer '{' and '}' to form a full json file.

Comment: Awesome. Want to test, then create the answer and close the question?

Comment: done, feedback from developer: The input should have at least an outer '{' and '}' to form a full json file.

Comment: What I meant was, Create an answer below explaining the situation. Then mark your question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments above, the answer is that when defining the response for the Watson Conversation service, the original input requires (at least) an outer '{' and '}' so that it is a syntactically correct json file.